# Catch exception if debugger is not attached

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

### Desired behaviour (the question)

In a C# application, what I would like is this:

When the debugger is not attached: -

1. Exception is thrown.
2. Exception is caught higher up in the stack.
3. Log error and continue.

When the debugger is attached: -

1. Exception is thrown.
2. Debugger breaks at the point where the exception is thrown.

To illustrate by way of an example, here is how it might work with a conditional catch (*I know that this is not supported in C#*):

*Note:* while I am showing an example of the exception being thrown by my code, it may be thrown by a 3rd party library.

```
static void DoSomething()
{
    //This is where I would like the debugger to break execution and show the exception
    throw new Exception( "Something went wrong!" );
}  

static public void DoSomeStep()
{
    try
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch( Exception exception when System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false ) //If the debugger is attached don't catch                
    {
        Console.WriteLine( exception.Message ); //Do some processing on the exception                
    }
}
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        DoSomeStep();
    }
}
```

### Background

This is not a big issue, since there are stack traces and logging to piece the information together, but I was wondering if there is a good way of achieving this, since it comes up now and then (and is one of those thousand cuts that I wouldn't mind doing without). Also, I have never found an ideal method, so I am interested if there is one.

It is particularly relevant in a program where there are a number of steps (such as running tests). During normal standalone operation, if any of these steps raise an exception an error should be logged and execution should move onto the next step. However, when running in the debugger the debugger should break at the point where the exception was raised. This will speed up the debugging process as you don't need to consult stack traces and the state of the local variables will be preserved.

The rest of this question describes things that I have already tried so that they are not repeated in the answers...

### Approaches that have already been considered

#### Conditional catch in VB DLL

I know that this is not supported in C#, but it is supported in VB.NET. So, I can get the desired behaviour by implementing the following in a VB.NET library (don't worry about the code too much, it basically wraps a method in a `try...catch` and calls an error handler if there is an exception and the debugger is not attached):

```
Public Module DebuggerNoCatch
    Public Function Run(Of T, U, V, W, X)(func As Func(Of T, U, V, W, X, Boolean), arg1 As T, arg2 As U, arg3 As V, arg4 As W, context As X, errorHandler As Action(Of System.Exception, X)) As Boolean
        Dim result As Boolean = False
        Try
            result = func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, context)
        Catch ex As Exception When Not Debugger.IsAttached
            errorHandler(ex, context)
            result = False
        End Try
        Return result
    End Function
End Module
```

Note that there need to be different overloads for `Run` depending on the number of arguments (in this case mine just happens to use 4 args). Also, there is a `Context` parameter for the cases where some state needs to be maintained between the method being called and the error handler.

Then my code looks something like this:

```
static bool DoSomething( int a, int b, int c, int d, RunContext context )
{
    //Now the debugger break at this point - hooray!
    throw new Exception( "Something went wrong!" );
    return true;
}

static void HandleException( Exception exception, RunContext context )
{
    //Only see this when not attached in the debugger
    Console.WriteLine( exception.Message ); //Do some processing on the exception                            
}

class RunContext{ } //context information - not used in this example

static public void DoSomeStep()
{
    DebuggerNoCatch.Run<int, int, int, int, RunContext>( DoSomething, 1, 1, 1, 1, new RunContext(), HandleException );
}
```

The drawbacks of this approach are: -

- The added complexity of another VB.NET DLL in the project.
- Not as intuitive as a simple `try...catch` - other people coming to the code for the first time would need to dig around to understand exactly what is going on.

#### Re-throw

The code (note the `throw`):

Example:

```
    static public void DoSomeStep()
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        catch( Exception exception )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( exception.Message ); //Do some processing on the exception
            //If the debugger is attached throw, otherwise just continue to the next step
            if( System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == true )
            {
                //This is where the debugger breaks execution and shows the exception
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem with this is that while `throw` preserves the stack trace, the debugger breaks at the line where the throw occurs rather than the original throw. It makes complete sense that it happens in this way, but it is not what I want to happen. It means that I need to look inside the exception for the stacktrace and then find the correct line of code. Also, the state of the local variables where the exception occurred is lost.

#### Wrapper method

Basically, just wrap the `try...catch` in a separate method:

```
    static void DoSomething()
    {
        //This is where I would like the debugger to break execution and show the exception
        throw new Exception( "Something went wrong!" );
    }
    static void DoSomethingContinueOnError()
    {
        try
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
        catch( Exception exception )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( exception.Message ); //Do some processing on the exception
        }
    }
    static public void DoSomeStep()
    {
        if( System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached == false )
        {
            DoSomethingContinueOnError();
        }
        else
        {
            DoSomething();                
        }            
    }
```

But, there are a number of problems with this:

- More code.
- Things quickly become unwieldy for more complicated cases, such as when there are more parameters or there are variables local to the `try...catch` that are set by need to be passed into 'DoSomething' by reference of if there are sub-steps.

#### Conditional compilation symbols

This is probably my least favourite option. In this case a conditional compilation symbol such as DEBUGGING is used (note DEBUG will not work because I may be running DEBUG without the compiler attached):

```
   #if !DEBUGGING           
        try
   #endif
        {
            DoSomething();
        }
   #if !DEBUGGING           
        catch( Exception exception )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( exception.Message ); //Do some processing on the exception
        }
   #endif
    }
```

The problems are: -

- This is all a bit of a headache to manage and I would invariably not have it set when I needed it. Specifically, the symbol and the fact that the debugger is attached are not related in any way other than by me manually setting the symbol definition.
- `#DEBUGGING` clutters the code and makes the `try...catch` less readable.

#### Other

- Visual Studio setting. I have also investigated the different Visual Studio exception break settings, but I want to turn the behaviour on for specific parts of the code, not for specific exceptions. Also, this should work across installations.
- Assembly IL. I have considered inline IL as an option to generate the conditional exception, but this requires post-build steps with 3rd party tools.
- I don't think that global (application) exception handlers will do it because the exception needs to be caught and logged lower down up in the application stack.

### Update - DebuggerStepThrough and Re-throw

Steven Liekens' comment indicates what seems to be a good solution - the `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute`. When this attribute is set on a method containing a re-throw, the debugger breaks at the original point of the exception, not where it is re-thrown as shown below:

```
static bool DoSomething()
{
     //This is where the debugger now breaks execution
     throw new Exception( "Something went wrong!" );
     return true;
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
static public void DoSomeStep()
{
    try
    {                
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch( Exception exception )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( exception.Message );
        if( Debugger.IsAttached == true )
        {
            //the debugger no longer breaks here
            throw;
        }
    }
}
static void Main( string[] args )
{          
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        DoSomeStep();
    }
}
```

The only drawback is if you do actually want to step into the code marked as `DebuggerStepThrough` or if there is an exception in this code. Though, this is a minor drawback because you can generally keep this code minimal.

Note the use of `Debugger.IsAttached` because I think its impact here is minimal and the likelihood of strange heisenbugs are minimal, but beware of using it as pointed out by Guillaume in the comments and use another option such as config setting when appropriate.

I will go with this unless a better way or someone raises concerns about it.

Comment: Check out the Microsoft enterprise library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx What you probably want is the Exception Handling Application Block or one of the other blocks. While it adds another dll (or even more) you gain well tested and used components instead of making your own (probably suboptimal) solution.

Comment: @Samuel, thanks for the thought. I can see that the Exception Handling Block would be useful for wrapping and propagating exceptions appropriately for each layer of an application stack, but there doesn't seem to be anything about preserving the exception location in the debugger. I would be hesitant to start down this path for my lightweight application without knowing that it would solve it.

Comment: What is to say against a global exception handler that is only present in your RC but not in your DEBUGGING build? That way every *unhandled* exception will be thrown where it occures while debugging and every exception will be handled by the global handler. Of course this doesn't interfere with all the **handled** exceptions

Comment: @MrPaulch - not sure I follow - the handled exception must not be handled when in the debugger, instead the debugger should break at the point they are thrown. Also, what happens if I run the RC in the debugger to track down an issue?

Comment: Look, you already suggested `#if DEBUGGING  try ... catch  ... etc.` yourself. I proposed you use that method not on every try catch phrase but on the definition of the global exception handler. So a global exception handler is only added if you compile your release verseion. In that case you won't need try catch blocks around regions where you don't expect an exception.

Comment: @MrPaulch - see last point in my question, I don't think that a global exception handler will do it - the exception needs to be handled lower down in the stack (where they are currently handled) - the application needs to catch the exception, log it and continue on with the next step (next iteration of `for` loop in the first example). However, when the debugger is attached (even in RC - which is why #if !DEBUG would not work), the debugger should halt at the point the exception is thrown. Also, a global exception handler is normally to log before exiting.

Comment: @MrPaulch - thanks, you made me realise I had a typo in my example for `#if DEBUGGING` it should be `#if !DEBUGGING`. Corrected now.

Comment: Oh if we are tidying up typos... parhaps you should use the `#DEBUG` constant as defined by the VS compiler ...
But im sorry to say, i don't have a better solution for this problem. I actually use something like Lorentz Vedeler provided giving up the benefit of having the debugger break at the exact location of the exception. Most of the time if i really want it to break precisly at the source i just comment the try catch blocks. This question is now on my fav. :)

Comment: @MrPaulch - thanks for the thoughts. The reason I did not use #DEBUG is because what I want to know is if the debugger is attached, not whether it is a DEBUG build. I could be debugging a release build. The problem (which is why this is my least favourite option) is that this is a compile time conditional, whereas whether the debugger is attached is determined at runtime.

Comment: I strongly advice against `Debugger.IsAttached` to avoid heisenbugs. Use a configuration file or something like that.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: @Guillaume - good point about Heisenbugs. For example, if there was an exception in the exception handling code, that would be tricky to track down. In this case the code that is different between debugging and non-debugging only executes on an exception and the exception will be caught immediately in the debugger, so I think the risk would be low, but still worth being mindful of.

Comment: Heisenbugs will occur in any case where there is different code run in one environment to another. I would probably use the config file as a matter of course when debugging which would have the same net result. Also all that additional code for the config / settings could cause heisenbugs in themselves. Though, I guess that with the config file you could remove the heisenbug with a config setting rather than needing to change the code. It might be better to minimize the difference between the code when in debugger and not. Also logging in non-debugger code that makes it clear would help.

Comment: @acarlon Heisenbugs disappears as soon as you want to observe them. Think about remote debugging your release on a computer on which an user sees an issue you are not able to reproduce on your dev machine. With Debugger.IsAttached, as soon as the remote debugger is attached, the program changes and the bug might change or disappear. You may be aware today but tomorrow other devs on the project won't. With a config file you can easily switch on or off problematic features. This happened to me trying to debug someone else's code. I lost two days !

Comment: @Guillaume - fair point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Exception Filters (C# 6+)

If you're using C# 6, this is easy to do with the new exception filter syntax:

```
try
{
    DoSomething()
}
catch (Exception e) when (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 5):

### DebuggerStepThrough and Re-throw (Accepted Answer)

As pointed out in the comments, when the `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` is set on a method containing a re-throw, the debugger breaks at the original point of the exception, not where it is re-thrown as shown below:

```
static bool DoSomething()
{
     //This is where the debugger now breaks execution
     throw new Exception( "Something went wrong!" );
     return true;
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
static public void DoSomeStep()
{
    try
    {                
        DoSomething();
    }
    catch( Exception exception )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( exception.Message );
        if( Debugger.IsAttached == true )
        {
            //the debugger no longer breaks here
            throw;
        }
    }
}
static void Main( string[] args )
{          
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        DoSomeStep();
    }
}
```

---

### LINQ-inspired alternative

I spent some time writing a LINQ-inspired `try...catch` wrapper that **does** actually support conditional catch blocks.

**Usage Example**

Before diving into the code, here's a usage example based on the original requirements:

```
DangerousOperation
    .Try(() =>
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    })
    .Catch((NotImplementedException exception) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }).When(ex => !Debugger.IsAttached)
    .Catch((NotSupportedException exception) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This block is ignored");
    }).When(ex => !Debugger.IsAttached)
    .Catch<InvalidProgramException>() /* specifying a handler is optional */
    .Catch()                          /* In fact, specifying the exception type is also optional */
    .Finally(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye");
    }).Execute();
```

This works by first evaluating the predicate specified in the `When()` statement before executing whatever is in the `Catch()` statement.

If you run the example, you'll notice that the debugger breaks on the line that causes the exception as the result of clever placement of a `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute.

**Source Code**

```
/// <summary>
/// Factory. Provides a static method that initializes a new try-catch wrapper.
/// </summary>
public static class DangerousOperation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a new try-catch block.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The 'try' block's action.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock"/> class that wraps the 'try' block.</returns>
    public static TryCatchBlock Try()
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a new try-catch block.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The 'try' block's action.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock"/> class that wraps the 'try' block.</returns>
    public static TryCatchBlock Try(Action action)
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock(action);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Wraps a 'try' or 'finally' block.
/// </summary>
public class TryCatchBlock
{

    private bool finalized;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock"/> class;
    /// </summary>
    public TryCatchBlock()
    {
        this.First = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock"/> class;
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The 'try' or 'finally' block's action.</param>
    public TryCatchBlock(Action action)
        : this()
    {
        this.Action = action;
    }

    protected TryCatchBlock(TryCatchBlock antecedent)
    {
        if ( antecedent == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("antecedent");
        }
        if ( antecedent.finalized )
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This block has been finalized with a call to 'Finally()'");
        }
        this.First = antecedent.First;
        this.Antecedent = antecedent;
        antecedent.Subsequent = this;
    }

    protected TryCatchBlock(TryCatchBlock antecedent, Action action)
        : this(antecedent)
    {
        this.Action = action;
    }

    public Action Action { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the 'try' block.
    /// </summary>
    public TryCatchBlock First { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the next block.
    /// </summary>
    public TryCatchBlock Antecedent { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the previous block.
    /// </summary>
    public TryCatchBlock Subsequent { get; private set; }


    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new 'catch' block and adds it to the chain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock{TException}"/> class that wraps a 'catch' block.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock<Exception> Catch()
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock<Exception>(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new 'catch' block and adds it to the chain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock{TException}"/> class that wraps a 'catch' block.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock<Exception> Catch(Action<Exception> action)
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock<Exception>(this, action);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new 'catch' block and adds it to the chain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TException">The type of the exception that this block will catch.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock{TException}"/> class that wraps a 'catch' block.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock<TException> Catch<TException>() where TException : System.Exception
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock<TException>(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new 'catch' block and adds it to the chain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TException">The type of the exception that this block will catch.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="action">The 'catch' block's action.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock{TException}"/> class that wraps a 'catch' block.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock<TException> Catch<TException>(Action<TException> action) where TException : System.Exception
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock<TException>(this, action);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new 'finally' block and finalizes the chain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock"/> class that wraps the 'finally' block.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock Finally()
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock(this) { finalized = true };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new 'finally' block and finalizes the chain.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">The 'finally' block's action.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock"/> class that wraps the 'finally' block.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock Finally(Action action)
    {
        return new TryCatchBlock(this, action) { finalized = true };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether this 'catch' wrapper can handle and should handle the specified exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if the exception can be handled; otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public virtual bool CanHandle(Exception exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the specified exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
    public virtual void Handle(Exception exception)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("This is not a 'catch' block wrapper.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the chain of 'try-catch' wrappers.
    /// </summary>
    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    public void Execute()
    {
        TryCatchBlock current = this.First;

        try
        {
            if ( current.Action != null )
            {
                current.Action();
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception exception )
        {
            while ( current.Subsequent != null )
            {
                current = current.Subsequent;

                if ( current.CanHandle(exception) )
                {
                    current.Handle(exception);
                    break;
                }

                if ( current.Subsequent == null )
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            while ( current.Subsequent != null )
            {
                current = current.Subsequent;
                if ( current.finalized && current.Action != null )
                {
                    current.Action();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Wraps a 'catch' block.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TException">The type of the exception that this block will catch.</typeparam>
public class TryCatchBlock<TException> : TryCatchBlock where TException : System.Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock{TException}"/> class;
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="antecedent">The 'try' or 'catch' block that preceeds this 'catch' block.</param>
    public TryCatchBlock(TryCatchBlock antecedent)
        : base(antecedent) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="TryCatchBlock{TException}"/> class;
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="antecedent">The 'try' or 'catch' block that preceeds this 'catch' block.</param>
    /// <param name="action">The 'catch' block's action.</param>
    public TryCatchBlock(TryCatchBlock antecedent, Action<TException> action)
        : base(antecedent)
    {
        this.Action = action;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a predicate that determines whether this block should handle the exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="predicate">The method that defines a set of criteria.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the current instance.</returns>
    public TryCatchBlock<TException> When(Predicate<TException> predicate)
    {
        this.Predicate = predicate;
        return this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether this 'catch' wrapper can handle and should handle the specified exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>True</c> if the exception can be handled; otherwise false.</returns>
    public override bool CanHandle(Exception exception)
    {
        if ( exception == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exception");
        }

        if ( !typeof(TException).IsAssignableFrom(exception.GetType()) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ( Predicate == null )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return Predicate((TException) exception);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the specified exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception">The exception.</param>
    public override void Handle(Exception exception)
    {
        if ( this.Action != null )
        {
            this.Action((TException) exception);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the exception handler.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<TException> Action { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the predicate that determines whether this wrapper should handle the exception.
    /// </summary>
    public Predicate<TException> Predicate { get; private set; }
}
```

**Final Notes**

This is a huge edit to my original post. Look at the change history for my initial solution.

Comment: Ha. Well, I have to give you a +1 for creativity and this looks like it would probably work (haven't tried it), but I think some of my coworkers would be surprised.

Comment: I think this the biggest amount of language hacks I've ever crammed into a single statement. I'm quite proud of myself.

Comment: @acarlon I've updated my answer with a serious solution.

Comment: @StevenLiekens calling Finally is mandatory using your DangerousOperation or the exception can be lost. It's not really clear as it is optional with regular exception handling.

Comment: @Guillaume what do you suggest?

Comment: You may register errors handler before trying the operation.

Comment: @Guillaume I've added an optional parameter to `Catch()` that specifies whether to throw if the exception was not handled, defaulting to `true`.

Comment: @StevenLiekens - thanks for the updated example. I may be missing something, but when `#if DEBUGGING` is set then wouldn't the debugger break at the throw (inside `#if DEBUGGING`) rather than where the exception was actually raised? If this is the case, then it would be similar to the *rethrow* example from my question. You may want the action() outside the `try...catch` if DEBUGGING and remove the throw.

Comment: In the usage example, it does actually break on the line that causes the exception. But maybe that's just because of the `[DebuggerStepThrough]` attribute.

Comment: Regardless, getting rid of the `try...catch` block would probably result in better optimized IL. This version is just less code to achieve the same result.

Comment: @acarlon I've replaced my answer with a robust solution that does everything you wanted, with syntax inspired by LINQ.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the huge effort on this. Your comment actually pointed to a neat solution - using DebuggerStepThrough with a re-throw. I have modified the answer to reflect this. If you are OK with it, I will accept it as the answer. The linq option is a good idea and may be useful to other people who come across this question, but in my case I need to keep things as simple as possible. Anyways, it looks like DebuggerStepThrough will solve it. Thanks again.

Comment: @StevenLiekens hmm, my whole purpose of editing it and accepting was so that you got the points, but it has been made part of the community wiki. Don't like the way that works.

Comment: @StevenLiekens - I have flagged the answer for moderation, hopefully it will be transfered back to you so that you get the points.

Comment: The funny thing is, I used the `[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]` only so you wouldn't accidentally step into my code. I had no idea it would cause the debugger to break higher up the call stack in case of an exception. But I guess it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the exception and catch a specific type of exception, that way when debugging there is no defined catch behavior for the exception and the debugger will break at the throwing code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            NotImplementedMethod();
        }
        catch (NotImplementedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static void NotImplementedMethod()
    {
        throw DebugException.Wrap(new NotImplementedException());//Breaks here when debugger is attached
    }
}

public class DebugException : Exception
{
    public static Exception Wrap(Exception innerException)
    {
        if(Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            return new DebugException(innerException);
        }
        else
        {
            return innerException;
        }
    }


    public DebugException(Exception innerException)
        : base("Debug exception", innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the exception could be thrown by third party code such as a referenced library. I will make that clearer in my question.